# Chef Cookbook requires both apt and yum

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I am new to Chef and I have noticed several cookbooks require both apt and yum in their metadata (example https://github.com/mdxp/nodejs-cookbook/). From what I understand, this is a contradictory requirement (use either apt or yum). When trying to provision with Chef when setting up a Vagrant VM, I get an error about the yum-epl cookbook not being included, even though I am using a Ubuntu box. Are conflicts like these supposed to be resolved automagically and something is wrong with my Vagrant configuration, or is this a poor set up cookbook? Drilling down through nodejs -> yum-epl -> yum cookbooks, I noticed that yum ultimately does not support Ubuntu.

Comment: The dependencies are against the "yum" and "apt" chef *cookbooks* not the software. Check the following receipe : https://github.com/mdxp/nodejs-cookbook/blob/master/recipes/install_from_package.rb  There is a platform check to see which cookbook is applied at runtime

Answer (score 0):

This cookbook require all package manager but choose internally
https://github.com/mdxp/nodejs-cookbook/blob/master/attributes/default.rb#L22

You must satisfy all requirements but it use apt, yum or source act on OS..